# Hibernate/NHibernate : how to persist subclass as instance of superclass

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, subclass

I have two classes I would like to persist via NHibernate:
- Cat, which has a name and an Id,
- Kitten, which is a subclass of Cat (no extra public properties).

For stupid reasons, I would like to know if it is possible to map Cat only? So that when I persist Kitten, it is saved as a Cat and when I reload it, it is loaded as a Cat.

Additional constraints : 
 - When trying, NHibernate crashed because it did not know Kitten. 
 - However I do not want to add a discriminator value, as I do not want Hibernate to instantiate the Kitten subclass.

Thank you very much!

EDIT : 
I forgot to write that using explicit ISession.Save("Cat", kitten) works. My problem occurs during a cascading save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, I guess I would have to use interfaces instead.